# Custom navigation controller to show fix top menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to create a fixed top menu with buttons to navigate through views, right now i have a navigation controller but I don't know how I can present a view controller from the navigation controller and I don't want the back functionality that included in the navigation controller. Is there an easier way were I can use a view controller as a menu and have it always presented static on top, even if the views underneath is changed?

What kind of controller would be easiest controller to use, to create a fixed top menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic setup.

The top bar is a UIToolbar with four barbutonItems

You could imbed the child view controller in the container view and switch the child view controllers when user tap the buttons.

[image: base view controller]

[image: basic setup]

Comment: how do I switch the child view container

Comment: @josef Sorry for the late reply, hope you'v already know how to switch view controllers, if not, please take a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html,  it is in "Adding and Removing a Child" section

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create your own parent view controller. I suggest you create a custom UIViewController that has a container view on it, and that you load child view controllers into the container view based on the user's interaction with your navigation menu. This is pretty straightforward to do.

Your view controller will probably act more like a tab bar controller than a navigation controller if I understand what you're looking for.

Comment: yes its sounds like a good plan, a tab bar is what im looking for. Is this possible to do using the story board?

Comment: Yes it's quite possible with storyboards. You'll have to create your own custom view controller class though. You'd instantiate that kind of view controller in your storyboard.